# Why is $_SESSION passed by reference in PHP 7?

Tags: php, session, php-7

I am upgrading from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7 and a strange problem occurred.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['test'] = true;
    $var = $_SESSION;
    session_unset();
    print_r($var);
```

PHP 5.6
Output:

```
Array
(
    [test] => 1
)
```

PHP 7
Output:

```
Array
(
)
```

I assume this is happening because `$_SESSION` is passed by reference, but why?

Comment: MCVE: https://3v4l.org/Lg0IE

Comment: change to:  `$var = &$_SESSION;` to get the same behavior in all PHP versions. I suspect you met 'copy on write' with earlier PHP version. https://3v4l.org/vv9PU

Comment: If i do that i get an empty array but i need to preserve the value stored in `$var`

Comment: Looks like a bug, please report on bugs.php.net.

Comment: workaround: `$var = array_merge(array(), $_SESSION);`. I have tested it with ordinary arrays and it works fine. i.e. 'copy on write'.  It is just `session_unset();` it is faulty with. ;-/ Array_merge version: https://3v4l.org/ve303

Comment: @RyanVincent It works thank you :)

Comment: Fixed upstream now, ref https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73273 and https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/c91f652ddbca784d9fc0c25fb2015923c6aca438.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To conclude, it was a bug that is now fixed starting with [PHP 7.0.13](http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.0.13). Details in comments of the question.